# Sails lift stopped working after attempt to implement relationships on model

Tags: sails.js

I have been lifting my sails app conveniently until I attempted to make some relationships work within my application(my first time implementing relationships in sails js though). After I tried running sails lift, it threw the error below:

```js
error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load!
error: 
error: Error: Can't insert key undefined, it violates the unique constraint
    at _AVLTree.insert (/Users../application001/node_modules/binary-search-tree/lib/avltree.js:273:19)
    at AVLTree.insert (/Users../application001/node_modules/binary-search-tree/lib/avltree.js:307:27)
    at Index.insert (/Users../application001/node_modules/nedb/lib/indexes.js:77:15)
    at Index.insertMultipleDocs (/Users../application001/node_modules/nedb/lib/indexes.js:114:12)
    at Index.insert (/Users../application001/node_modules/nedb/lib/indexes.js:69:33)
    at Index.reset (/Users../application001/node_modules/nedb/lib/indexes.js:55:23)
    at /Users../application001/node_modules/nedb/lib/datastore.js:107:21
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Datastore.resetIndexes (/Users../application001/node_modules/nedb/lib/datastore.js:106:29)
    at /Users../application001/node_modules/nedb/lib/persistence.js:293:23
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:61:3)
```

I reverted all the codes to how it was without relating the models, sails lift would still not work even if I alter, drop or safe.

I had to revert my code to a much earlier commit when I have not created a number of models at all for it me to run sails lift successfully. I tried to comment all the new model codes, yet sails failed to lift

How can I resolve this issue please?

I am using the default database that comes with sails.js (datastore is set to default)

Here is an example of one of my models. Archived.js

```js
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    userId: {
      model:'personalinfo',
      //type: 'number',
      required: true,
      //unique: true,
    },
    comment:{
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },
    createdBy:{
      type: 'number',
      required: true
    },
    
  },

};
```

PersonalInfo.js looks like this:

```js
module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    fullName:{
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },

    phone:{
     type: 'string',
     required: true
   },

   location:{
     type: 'string',
     required: true
   },

   age:{
     type: 'integer',
     required: true
   },

   email:{
     type: 'string',
     required: true
   },

   gender:{
    type: 'string',
    required: true
  },

  userId:{
    type: 'integer',
    required: true,
  },
  
  archived: {
    collection: 'archived',
    via: 'userId'
  },

  deleted: {
    collection: 'deleted',
    via: 'userId'
  },

  picked: {
    collection: 'picked',
    via: 'userId'
  },


  },

};
```

And my action looks something like this

```js
fn: async function (inputs) {
    const archived = await Archived.find().populate('personal');
    console.log(archived);
    // var zookeepers = await Zookeeper.find();
    return archived;
  }
```

Comment: We need more to answer this question. Can you (1) tell us what sort of database you are currently using? And (2) can you provide an example of a model you added with a `unique` attribute that seemed to case the problem?

Comment: @arbuthnott I have updated the question showing an example model. Thank you

Comment: This one is hard to diagnose, but my best guess is - look at the data you have stored in `.tmp/localDisk.db` - that's a text file that sails uses as a "database" by default. Some model that you have saved (in json) in there is failing one of your model requirements, like uniqueness, or maybe an attribute that's supposed to be an association has no matching id in another collection, etc. My guess is you have bad data there. You can just edit and save the file then relift to see if it works.

Comment: I later found out that my relationships where not properly written.